# Для чего AccessType.FIELD и AccessType.PROPERTY в @Access?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Для чего эти аннотации, и какие плюсы и минусы `AccessType.FIELD` и `AccessType.PROPERTY`. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Habr](https://habr.com/post/265061/):

> @Access нужна для определения типа доступа (access type) для класса
>   entity, суперкласса, embeddable или отдельных атрибутов, то есть как
>   JPA будет обращаться к атрибутам entity, как к полям класса (FIELD)
>   или как к свойствам класса (PROPERTY), имеющие гетеры (getter) и
>   сетеры (setter).

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваши поля были доступны как обычные поля, но есть одно поле, для доступа к которому вы хотите использовать геттер или сеттер, вы можете предоставить аннотацию `@Access`.
Эта аннотация имеет два режима: `AccessType.FIELD` и `AccessType.PROPERTY`.
Мы можем явно указать тип доступа, используя `AccessType.PROPERTY` или `AccessType.FIELD` в `@Access` аннотации. Мы можем использовать `@Access` на уровне класса, поля или метода. Мы можем даже смешивать два типа в одном классе сущностей.

Перевод ответа с [ответа с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874528/what-is-the-purpose-of-accesstype-field-accesstype-property-and-access):

> По умолчанию тип доступа определяется местом, в котором находится ваш
>   идентификатор(`@ Id`). Если он будет в поле - это будет
>   [`AccessType.FIELD`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html#FIELD), если он будет в геттере - это
>   [`AccessType.PROPERTY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AccessType.html#PROPERTY).
>
> Иногда вам может потребоваться аннотировать не поля, а свойства
>   (например, потому что вы хотите иметь какую-то произвольную логику в
>   геттере или потому, что вы так предпочитаете). В такой ситуации вы
>   должны определить геттер и аннотировать его как `AccessType.PROPERTY`.

Обобщение: вы можете использовать аннотацию `AccessType.FIELD` для 'обычного' доступа к полю, и аннотацию `AccessType.PROPERTY` для доступа к полю через **get/set**.